# How can I remap <CapsLock> to <Escape> in the fish shell?

Tags: vi, fish, keymapping

I've just installed fish shell in my archlinux. Because I use vi-mode in fish, I want to remap my `<CapsLock>` to `<Escape>`. How can I archieve it by adding something into my `~/.config/config.fish`.

I've see the document of `bind`, but I don't know how to express `<Escape>` and `<CapsLock>`.

Comment: You will have to modify your terminal configuration to change the behavior of those keys. Pressing CapsLock doesn't normally send any characters for Fish to capture and interpret.

Comment: @KurtisRader You are right, `fish_key_reader` cannot accept <CapsLock> key.

Comment: It is not that `fish_key_reader` cannot accept (i.e., recognize) the CapsLock key. It is that no terminal sends a sequence of characters when CapsLock is pressed. CapsLock is fundamentally different from other keys such as Tab which send a sequence of characters.

Comment: I know. You mean `Caps` is other thing that does not exist as a character. And the other keys, like `Tab`, is characters. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the same thing you would do for any key, as [the fish documentation explains](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#key-sequences):

You run `fish_key_reader`, you press your key (or key combination), and you'll see what that says.

If it doesn't do anything, which I would expect for capslock, that's because the terminal doesn't pass on the key to the shell. (press another key to exit fish_key_reader)

If that is the case, it would be impossible to bind it through config.fish, and you would have to change it in your terminal or desktop settings.

---

If you *do* get a key, you wouldn't "remap it to escape", you would bind it to the same thing as escape. Assuming you're interested in insert mode, you would run

```
bind -M insert \e
```

to find out what escape (`\e`) is bound to in insert mode:

```
bind --preset -M insert \e 'if commandline -P; commandline -f cancel; else; set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f backward-char repaint-mode; end'
```

And then you would bind your key the same. E.g. if you wanted ctrl-g to do the same thing, fish_key_reader explains:

```
bind \cG 'do something'
```

so it is `\cG`, so you would bind:

```
bind -M insert \cG 'if commandline -P; commandline -f cancel; else; set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f backward-char repaint-mode; end'
```

without the `--preset` because that denotes a binding that belongs to the default binding preset.

Comment: `fish_key_reader` is a nice command. It make me understanding my `fish` cannot accept `<CapsLock>` key.